# Optimization in a time based algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I'm writing an algorithm for this problem, the algorithm is simple, I've already wrote the code but I can't see any possible optimization:

> I have a bucket with 100 stones and 5 children that use it for decorate their sand castles.
>   Every child pick up a stone repeatedly every a certain span of time, every child is independent from the others, more children can pick up a stone in the same time, there are 5 children in totals:
>
> - Eric pick up a stone every 5 minutes
> - Mark pick up a stone every 10 minutes
> - Lara pick up a stone every 7 minutes
> - Emma pick up a stone every 3 minutes
> - Frank pick up a stone every 3 minutes
>
> How many minutes exactly we need for empty the bucket?
>
> To be more clear: after 10 minutes, Erick has up two stones (minute 5 and minute 10), while Emma has 3 stones (minute 3, 6 and 9).
>
> So after 10 minutes the children have 2 + 1 + 1 + 3 + 3 = 10 stones in total, there are 90 stones in the bucket

This is my code (Python 3):

```py
children_rate = [3, 3, 5, 7, 10]
bucket = 100

minutes = 0

while True:
    minutes += 1
    for child in children_rate:
        if minutes % child == 0:
            bucket -= 1
            if bucket == 0:
                print('bucket empty in',minutes,'minutes')
                exit()
```

This code works, in this case the minutes required are 91,  but I can't use this code for process a bucket with 1 million of stones and 500 children.

The only optimization I can see is to transform the mod operation in a sum/add operation because division/multiplications are more expensive. I can use numpy arrays and so on but nothing that can really speed up the process.

I've tried to adapt the problem to some typical know problem described in my algorithm textbook without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is binary search for the answer.

Suppose the answer is `X` minutes.
Then you know how many stones each child will take during that time.
If the total number of stones taken turns out to be less than expected, `X` needs to be higher.
Otherwise, search in the lower half.

In code:

```
children_rate = [3, 3, 5, 7, 10]
bucket = 100

lo, hi = 0, bucket * max (children_rate)
while lo < hi:
    me = (lo + hi) // 2
    if sum (me // i for i in children_rate) < bucket:
        lo = me + 1
    else:
        hi = me

print (lo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can turn the algorithm around, so that for a given number of minutes you calculate how many stones have been used by all the children.

```
def compute_stones(minutes)
    stones = 0
    for child in children_rate:
        stones += minutes // child  # integer division
    return stones
```

Then you can do a binary chop to find the number of minutes at which stones = 100

Comment: Since the question is tagged `python-3.x`, shouldn't floor division be `//`?

Answer (score 1):

Each child picks a stone in some period, all children together pick stones in some pattern which has a period as well. The period of this pattern is [Least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) of each child's period. It can be computed in several ways but let's use a factorization of each period in this case.

```
3  =   3
5  =     5
7  =       7
10 = 2 * 5
```

So common period is `210 = 2 * 3 * 5 * 7`. In this time Eric picks 42 stones, Mark picks 21 stones, Lara picks 30 stones and Emma and Frank picks 70 stones each. It is 233 stones each 210 minutes. If you have 1 million stones in a bucket, they pick 999803 stones in 901110 minutes and you will run your original code for the rest of 197 stones. Easy, isn't it?

Comment: Even for a few children, the period can turn out to be very large (as large as the product of periods all children, for example, if they are different prime integers). So this approach can be impractical unless we know the periods of the children are all very small integers, or otherwise guaranteed to have a small LCM.